# How i can communicate with two computer with RJ45 port and php?

Tags: php, port

How i can communicate with two computer with RJ45 port and php? And How can communicate two computers using serial port and php?

Comment: Using their assigned IP addresses. You should delegate the network connection specifics to the operating system. Let it create the LAN over TCP/IP and then you can just use it in a way which doesn't depend on the physical layer.

Comment: I have LAN, next is I want to send a string form one device and it is to be read from other device using php.

Comment: Over what protocol? Is there a web-server on any of the devices that will be used or will you implement a custom server/client interface? If it is the case of the former you just need to send an HTTP request via cURL (or similar) and if it is the latter you need to use sockets and have PHP scripts running on both ends.

Comment: i have to interface a clinical laborotory machine, cobas c111 with php. So it is not possible to run script on other end.

Comment: Is the lab machine running any server of any kind? Don't you have any instructions on how the lab machine can accept data?

Comment: Lab machine accept ASTM protocol, but, i have to receive the message and send message to it... How it is possible with php using port

Comment: Create a socket script to send and receive data. Read up the ASTM protocol definition to know what format the messages need to be and implement a PHP parser for them. I don't know of any library that does this and I have no idea of that protocol specification (and don't intend to learn it).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with PHP sockets.

**PHP Socket examples:**
http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php

Comment: I have tried the code shown in this page, but the page doesn't show a result. running the page continuously and not stopping.

Comment: Than you should adjust your question and show us what you tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

to communicate two computers you need a crossover cable. it is like your normal ethernet cable but it is crimped differently

Comment: I have LAN connection between the computers and both have ip like, 192.168.0.41 and 192.168.0.43

Comment: the LAN port is okay, but you need a cable called a crossover cable. A crossover cable is used to enable communication of devices with equal intelligence such as a computer to computer, a router to a router and a switch to a switch. it is good that the ip's are not identical. but let me get this straight, are you trying to access a service from one computer?